# How to prevent the <p> and <br> elements in ContentEditable div

Tags: typescript, dom-events, contenteditable

When press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, automatically the paragraph and page break elements are added to the editor. Suggest how to prevent the unwanted elements from the editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> `prevent the <p> and <br> elements in ContentEditable div`

The browser behaviour is inconsistent with ContentEditable. Use something better e.g. https://draftjs.org/ from facebook

## More

Lots of people have tried (like you) and deserted.

- http://codemirror.net/doc/internals.html
- https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480
- https://medium.com/content-uneditable/contenteditable-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-261a38555e9c

Comment: Not for plugins.I am doing for textEditor.